# How fast can a Schmitt trigger operate? Can I use it for signal conditioning digital serial data?

Tags: serial, clock, digital-communications, rs485, schmitt-trigger

I would like to know if I could use a Schmitt trigger chip (e.g., 74HCT14, CD40106B and 74AC14) to clean a 12MHz serial digital signal that has gone through a long cable and will pass through multiple devices (each device will decode the signal) and therefore is not perfect.

I am aware of termination resistors and communication standards such as RS-485, but if I could reconstruct the signal at each node of the chain, I imagine that could be more appropriate for my application (and possibly I could try to combine this with the RS-485, for example.)

Comment: > "How fast can a Schmitt trigger operate?" : Read The Fine Manual for the specific device you're planning to use. Different ones will have different limits.

Comment: @brhans It's probably not obvious to most people how to translate propagation delay/transmission time from some datasheet into suitability for a certain baudrate.

Comment: A schmidt cannot clean up a signal that has been degraded by reflections on the line, or by pulse width distortions caused by passing through multiple devices.

Comment: the datasheet of these devices usually doesn't specify the max frequency. For example, the 74HCT14 only shows test conditions at 1MHz. CD40106B does show a limit of a wave shaper up to 1MHz.

Comment: @Neil_UK, what if we combine it with a diff driver (e.g. RS485) which will minimise the reflection?

Comment: @Lundin possibly true - but the question is unanswerable without knowing which part the OP wants to use.

Comment: best way to deal with reflections on lines is to design and use the lines right, not go cobbling this or that IC in an effort to fix the damage. Like the best way to deal with a car hitting things is not to strap mattresses to it, but to drive it in a way that you don't hit things. AC14 definitely quick enough for 12 MHz, CD4x series not fast enough, HCT series may well be struggling, but may work

Comment: A 74AC14 is certainly fast enough, I just tested two inverters in series at 38 MHz. But, at these rates, the rise/fall times are just as important as the propagation delays. You will need to perform at lot more detailed calculations and/or run some tests.

Comment: Btw at these high baudrates you ought to use slope control, in which case a Schmitt trigger isn't such a bad idea. To ensure that the slope control doesn't lead to the UART misreading the logic voltage levels.